# Combine data in 2 tables

Tags: excel, vba

I want to achieve this via VBA in my Excel archive. This cannot be done using simply excel buttons/formulas, I need it to be a VBA Macro.

Here is my case:

I have 3 different Classification levels. These are editable, so anyone can fill the Classification table with their own procedures. I just want to write a VBA code that takes the tables and join the names dynamically.

EXAMPLE:

TABLE 1

| CAR | MODEL |
| --- | --- |
| Tesla | S |
| Toyota | Corolla |
| Toyota | Avensis |

TABLE 2

| MODEL | COLORS |
| --- | --- |
| S | Red |
| S | Blue |
| Corolla | Black |
| Avensis | White |
| Avensis | Red |
| Avensis | Pink |

What I want to reach:

RESULT TABLE

| CLASSIFICATION |
| --- |
| Tesla - S - red |
| Tesla - S - blue |
| Toyota - Corolla - Black |
| Toyota - Avensis - White |
| Toyota - Avensis - Red |
| Toyota - Avensis - Pink |

If somebody adds a new car, with new models and new colors, if I run the macro the CLASSIFICATION TABLE must take that updates.

So grateful if somebody helps me with this :(

Comment: Looks like a pretty standard SQL query to me, shouldn't you start with that approach?

Comment: Hi Dom. The thing is, i have that tables on EXCEL SHEETS, and users can manually fill that tables. The result table will be in another Excel Sheet on the same Workbook.

Comment: If i could convert my TABLE 1 to me RESULT TABLE would be also a great job, forget about relations between tables.

Comment: @RaxGG you can convert Table 2 to your result table. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Copy `Table 2` add a column infront of column A "Model" and name it `Classification`.
2. Add the following formula in A2 and pull it down.

   ```
   =INDEX('Table 1'!A:A,MATCH(B2,'Table 1'!B:B,0)) & " - " & B2 & " - " & C2
   ```
3. If you want values (instead of formulas) copy column A (with the formulas) and paste it as values in the same place, then delete B and C.

[image]

Comment: Can i ask you something? If my table is a CAR - MODEL - COLOR (just one table, not two) Can you type me the INDEX FORMULA please? Thank you for all :)

Comment: @RaxGG If Car is Column A, Model B and Color C then write in D: `=A:A & " - " & B:B & " - " & C:C`